# Azure devops multi stage YML build pipelines does not allow agent pool name as variable with approvals & checks on agent pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure devops multi-stage YML build-pipeline does not allow agent pool name as variable if approvals & checks are applied on that agent & it gives below error on pipeline run.

**Error**

> ##[error]The job is using protected resource(s) for which checks have not been evaluated queue:MY_AGENT_PROD, queue:MY_AGENT_PROD. For more details, refer to https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks.

**Example**:

Private Agent pool name is: "MY_AGENT_PROD",
Applied Security > Approvals & Check > Approvals (Added one groups which can approve it)

My Pipeline: Added Pipeline Variable agent.pool.name=MY_AGENT_PROD

```
stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: "READ_PARAM"
        pool:
          name: $(agent.pool.name)
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo appName: $(appName)
```

Observation: If use pool name directly instead of variable name, it works fine.

Is this a bug in ADO pipeline?

we do not want to hard code agent pool name in pipeline.

Adding my.agent.pool in pipeline variable
[image]

Comment: Did you consider [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) to replace this variable?

Comment: But for runtime parameters also we need to hardcode it in pipeline which we do not want. and if you are saying about text box at runtime so that also we do not want (user will have to type the pool name every time when he will run it).

Comment: Yes, I am using pipeline runtime parameter got agent key & value:  agent.pool.name=MY_AGENT_PROD

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same issue when I use the macro method to use variable( `$(variable)`).

To solve this issue, you need to change to use the [template expression][1] (`${{ variables.var }}`).

At the same time, you need to modify the variable name to `agent_pool_name`.

Here is my example:

```
variables:
  agent_pool_name : my.agent.pool

stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: "READ_PARAM"
        pool:
          name: ${{ variables.agent_pool_name }}
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo appName: AA
```

The reason for this issue could be that the process of adding check occurs before runtime.

Comment: are you keeping the agent pool name hardcoded (default) here in "variables:
  agent_pool_name : default"

Comment: i m using pipeline variable to keep agent.pool.name=MY_AGENT_NAME, and it give the same error even after using template expression

Comment: Where did you set the variable？In Variable Group or othe places?

Comment: in Pipeline variable: Azure devops > pipeline > select pipeline > edit > variable:

Comment: When you define the variable in the variable Option,  the value will not be passed to YAML after template compilation, so this issue still exists, you need to define the variable to Yaml and it will work

Comment: no, it works if "i do not apply approvals & check on agent pool", as soon as i apply approvals & check on agent it does not work